gcc can't find stdint.h
I'm trying to build libpd from source.  I downloaded the source as well as the pure-data submodule from https://github.com/libpd/libpd.  I used git checkout 0.14.1 to change to what I believe is the most recent stable release.
When I run make from inside the libpd folder, I get this error:
cc -DPD -DUSEAPI_DUMMY -DPD_INTERNAL -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -I./libpd_wrapper -I./libpd_wrapper/util -I./pure-data/src -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -fPIC -DHAVE_ENDIAN_H -I"/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include" -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_LIBDL -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -DLIBPD_EXTRA       -c -o pure-data/src/d_arithmetic.o pure-data/src/d_arithmetic.c
In file included from pure-data/src/m_pd.h:79,
                 from pure-data/src/d_arithmetic.c:11:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
    9 | # include_next <stdint.h>
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: pure-data/src/d_arithmetic.o] Error 1


It looks like the pure-data submodule uses the #include_next directive to find <stdint.h>, so here is gcc's include path:
# echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"

If I understand correctly, gcc should be searching for stdint.h in /usr/local/include rather than /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include anyway, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.
I'm running BookwormPup64.

Is stdint.h installed in the paths you expected?

It's installed in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/include, but not in /usr/local/include.  I realized I misread the error and the #include_next directive is coming from the stdint.h file, trying to point to a different that doesn't exist.  I have libc6-dev installed, so I'm not sure why the stdint.h file I have isn't the correct one.

That header is to support a hosted c library, at least going off header guards.  On my system (Gentoo Linux) I have both /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/stdint.h and /usr/include/stdint.h.  If you don't have the real stdint.h installed, you'll have to do some research on the proper package to install.

Okay, this is a great jumping off point for me.  Thanks for the advice!
